# Combing PDF's using pdftk and paste command to match file names

Tags: bash, paste, pdftk

Trying to write a simple script for combining PDF's with similar names

Script so far

```
f1=filesa.txt
f2=filesb.txt
paste $f1 $f2
pdftk $f1 $2 output "$f1"_combined.pdf
```

Paste command output these correctly into two data columns

```
A001.pdf    A001_T.pdf
A0002.pdf   A0002_T.pdf
A03.pdf A03_T.pdf
A0004.pdf   A0004_T.pdf
```

The outcome that I'm looking for is to combine the PDF's with similar names into a new file with "_combined" at the end

I'm missing a logical step to put this files into a while read or something?

Comment: @Cyrus I'm using filesa.txt and filesb.txt as these contain the filenames of the PDF's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a one-liner solution:

```
paste filesa.txt filesb.txt | while read -r fileA fileB; do pdftk $fileA $fileB output ${fileA%.*}_combined.pdf; done
```

You need to iterate over the result of `paste`, which I did with the while loop.

Comment: Thats great - Just missing the pdf prefix at the end of _combined and has it on front of combined

Comment: @Grimlockz: Try this: `${fileA%.*}_combined.pdf`

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about that. Updated thanks to Cyrus.